# Bose-Hubbard Parameters from Band Structure

Tags: optical-lattices

Could someone explain me how to compute numerically the parameters J and U and $\mu$ and the Wannier functions in the Bose-Hubbard model: 
$H=J\sum\limits_{j,1}^{L-1} (a_j^{+} a_{j+1}+ a_{j} a_{j+1}^{+})+U\sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} n_j(n_j-1) -\mu \sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} n_j$
for a given a lattice with lattice spacing $a$ and depth $V_0$?

Comment: See [R. Walters et. al., PRA **87**, 043613 (2013)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2213) for a full theoretical treatment and accompanying open-access MATLAB code.